# Trivial question on radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I saw the following equation : $$x^{2/3}$$

Instead of the correct expansion 
$$x^{2/3} = ( \sqrt[3]{x} ) ^ 2$$

I made the following mistake 
$$x^{2/3} = ( \sqrt[3]{x^2} ) $$

In order not to make the same mistake again I tried to formulate my mistake in terms of some rule but I do not really see what rule I trespassed. I would appreciate if could let me know.

Edit : 
I see that in this particular case 
$$( \sqrt[3]{x} ) ^ 2 = ( \sqrt[3]{x^2} ) $$

but what if the equation was $$x^{2/4}$$

then

$$( \sqrt[4]{x} ) ^ 2 \neq ( \sqrt[4]{x^2} ) $$

as two functions would have different domains. I know, I could simplify the 2/4 to 1/2 but for the sake of argument I choose not to and I am not aware of any rule that forces me to do the simplification.

Comment: i dont see mistake

Comment: It's just the same. No mistake.

Comment: The only rule you need to avoid similar problems is:$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\ne x$$Also, see that $(\sqrt x)^2$ is undefined for negative numbers.

Comment: @DonAntonio Please disregard the prior comment.

Answer (score 3):

Instead, try to *prove* that indeed
$$\sqrt[3]{x^2} \ =\ (\sqrt[3]x)^2$$
for all real $x$.

Comment: Note that while this goes for all reals, $x^{2/3}$ is only valid for _non-negative_ reals $x$.